# Google sheets Auto Highlight

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have created a google sheet to schedule appointments for a clinic. I am looking to find a method which will highlight the cell or row based on a client name? This can be based off a script or separate google sheet.

For example, I want the following names to be highlighted if they are entered.

John Smith
Susan Johnson
Ted Jones

When someone enters their name in the Column (Name), then that row or cell will be highlighted with a color.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to Format -> conditional formatting and then set the rules you want for the range of cells where you want that highlighting rule to be applied. You can highlight if the cell is blank/ not blank, or if the cell contains specific text that you will need to stipulate.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also want to be sure that they spell the name correctly so that the conditional formatting actually works. If you know all the names in advance, you can even create a dropdown list using the data validation tool to prevent typos.

Data > Validation > List from a range or items